# notepad++ regular expression, replace space between numbers

Tags: notepad++

I need to replace spaces between two numbers with ","

```
0 0
```

with

```
0,0
(X,X)
```

Search part is easy

```
Search:\d \d
```

but

`replace:\d,\d`  - doesn't work
I want first number and last number to stay the same.
so `Search: 45 90`
will result with: `45,90`

Comment: [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: `replace with: \1,\2`

Comment: Use capture groups for each digit: `(\d) (\d)` and use them in the replacement part: `$1,$2`. `$1` stands for the value contained in group 1, same for `$2`